# Issue with adding elements to Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill the Series `series`. `print(l.get_results())` returns the Series's as I expected them to be, however, `print(series)` returns an empty series and I don't know how else to append the Series's to `series`.

```
series = pd.Series()
for l in b_list:
    series.append(l.get_results())
    print(l.get_results())
    count += 1
print(series)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`series.append()` returns a copy, and therefore your original `series` has not been modified at all. Try this:

```
series = pd.Series()
for l in b_list:
    series = series.append(l.get_results())
    print(l.get_results())
    count += 1
print(series)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably more efficient to use a list comprehension to generate your expected values and then pass them to the Series initializer.

Appending to the existing series is inefficient because it creates a new copy.

```
series = pd.Series([l.get_results() for l in b_list])
```